# Multiple Values in Stored in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem in my loop. Basically I am using WordPress User Meta function `update_user_meta` and I have created a function which adds the keys and values in the `usermeta` table. The issue is that the first value which I add using `add_user_meta` function is duplicated twice. I think the `elseif` is also running after I run `if` because when I removed `elseif` there were no duplicate entries.

```
/**
 * [Add Custom User Meta Data]
 * @param [int] $userid    [User ID]
 * @param [string] $meta_key  [Meta Key to Alter]
 * @param [string] $new_value [Mata Value to Alter]
 */
function wp_postquiz_update_user_metadata($userid, $meta_key, $new_value ) {

    $oldMeta = get_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, true);

    if ( !get_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, false) ) {

        add_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, $new_value);

    } elseif ( is_array($oldMeta) && !in_array($new_value, $oldMeta) ) {

        if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) ){

            $oldMeta[] = $new_value;
            update_user_meta( $userid, $meta_key, $oldMeta);

        }
    }
}
```

I need to update the old values including the new values, if there is another way to do this please let me know ..

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

use [update_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) function only !  , it adds the user meta if it not found

Answer (score 0):

Its not the `update_user_meta` function. I think it was the multidimensional array I was using. Never mind, I ended up using this code, in case anyone needs it ..

```
/**
 * [Add Custom User Meta Data]
 * @param [int] $userid    [User ID]
 * @param [string] $meta_key  [Meta Key to Alter]
 * @param [string] $new_value [Mata Value to Alter]
 */
function wp_postquiz_update_user_metadata($userid, $meta_key, $new_value ) {

    if ( !get_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, true) ) {

        $newMeta = array($new_value);
        add_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, $newMeta);

    } elseif (get_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, true) ) {

        // will return false if the previous value is the same as $new_value
        if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) ){

            $oldMeta = get_user_meta($userid, $meta_key, true);

            if( is_array($oldMeta) && !in_array($new_value, $oldMeta) ){
                $oldMeta[] = $new_value;
                update_user_meta( $userid, $meta_key, $oldMeta);
            } 
        }
    } else {

        wp_die('An error occured' );

    }

}
```